# I have an error doing a select in SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to do this at `onUpgrade()` in my Android Java App:

```
try {
    db.execSQL("SELECT fechacontrol from parametres", null);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE parametres ADD COLUMN fechacontrol BIGINT");
}
```

My problem is, the column `fechacontrol` exists, but I always end up in the exception block, then the app crashes because of a duplicated column name.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you all.

Comment: Paste your error code.

Comment: ^ also, your stacktrace

Comment: Yep, @Shaishav maybe you're right, comment the line `e.printStackTrace();` and test again.

Comment: The printsStackTrace() im getting is IllegalArgumentException:  Empty bindArgs

Answer (score 1):

`execSQL(anything, null)` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` due to null bindargs. That's why you always end up in the `catch`. There is `execSQL(String)` overload for executing SQL without bindargs.

However, database upgrades should not be done like this. The schema version number is stored in the database file and you get it as a param in `onUpgrade()`. Use that information to deduce what needs to be updated.

Comment: forget the null on (anything, null), i mistaked posting, because i had a rawQuery that i changed for db.execSQL posting, but anyway, does the same error